# Which tool should I use for responsive web development: Chrome web developer tool or simply resize the window?

Tags: html, css, web, responsive-design, media-queries

I have been trying to make a responsive website for mobile devices . I have found two ways to test responsive design:

1. By resizing the window
2. Using Google Chrome developer's tools

In both of them I get a different view. Which one gives me the right view, as I use `font-size` and `padding` in **'em'**.

Comment: Well, resizing your window doesn't necessarily change your resolution, it just changes the width of the body container or divs, etc... dependent on how you have responsively coded them. You wouldn't see a change in font size in the same way you would by utilizing the developer tool to imitate the actual resolution/screen size of other devices.

Answer (score 0):

Resizing browser window is not Responsive. While developing Responsive applications the easiest, but yet not perfect, way is using Chrome's Developer tools. Even that may give you different results, because mobile device screens are using not just width/height but also dpi. So 320 iphone6s screen is not going to be perfect match for 320px resized browser or equivalent android device.

Answer (score 0):

Go for chrome developer tools. It's a great way of checking responsiveness. It comes with dimensions of popular mobile and tablet devices. So you can check for a variety of device at once.
Simply resizing the browser is not a right way of checking responsiveness.
Recently I built a page that works fine with both the ways you mentioned. You can check it [here](http://priyanjitdey94.github.io).
Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 0):

I would say Chrome Dev Tools is the best bet for a local snapshot.

However, if you have access to one or more mobile devices you may want to launch the site on Heroku or another production environment and view it from the actual device.

An iPhone 6 for example, I find Chrome does not take into account the address bar or bottom nav in safari so things can be slightly off from the Chrome Dev view of iPhone 6.